# Angular : Use a default translate language in full app

Tags: angular, typescript, output, decorator, eventemitter

I'm using ngx-translation package to internationalize my angular app and I want to set the chosen language by user in the authentication interface as default language for all app, the drop down list of language is placed in the login page and in the navbar, the problem is when the user change the default language which is french to other language and login the language return to the default one !!

navbar.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
// import { Socket } from 'ngx-socket-io';
import { SocketIOService } from '../../socket-io.service'
import { TranslateService, LangChangeEvent } from '@ngx-translate/core';

import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})

export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  viewChecked: any = false;
  user: any;
  notifications: any[];

  avatarDropeddown: any = false;
  notifDropeddown: any = false;
  textDir: string = 'ltr';
  lng: string

  constructor(
    public translate: TranslateService,
    private router: Router,
    private http: HttpClient,
    // private socket: Socket
    private socketService: SocketIOService
  ) {
    translate.setDefaultLang('fr');
    translate.use('fr');

    this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe((event: LangChangeEvent) => {
      if (event.lang == 'ar') {
        this.textDir = 'rtl';
      }
      else {
        this.textDir = 'ltr';
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    this.http.get('api/notifications/byUser/' + this.user._id).subscribe((notifications: any) => {
      this.notifications = notifications
    });

    this.socketService.onNewNotif().subscribe(msg => {
      this.http.get('api/notifications/byUser/' + this.user._id).subscribe((notifications: any) => {
        this.notifications = notifications
      });
    });

  }
  changeLang(val) {
    this.translate.use(val)
  }

  logout() {
    this.http.post('api/auth/signout', {}).subscribe(res => {
      this.avatarDropeddown = false;
      localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth');
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let that = this;
    $(document).click(function(e) {
      if ($(e.target).closest("#avatarButton").length > 0) {
        return false;
      }
      if ($(e.target).closest("#dropdownContent").length > 0) {
        return false;
      }

      if ($(e.target).closest("#notifications").length > 0) {
        return false;
      }
      if ($(e.target).closest("#notificationDropdownContent").length > 0) {
        return false;
      }
      if (that.avatarDropeddown == true) {
        that.avatarDropdown();
      }
      if (that.notifDropeddown == true) {
        that.notificationDropdown();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

*** auth.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { TranslateService, LangChangeEvent } from '@ngx-translate/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-auth',
  templateUrl: './auth.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./auth.component.css']
})
export class AuthComponent implements OnInit {
  public loading: boolean;
  user: FormGroup;

  currentLanguage: string

  constructor(public translate: TranslateService, private http: HttpClient, private authservice: AuthService, private router: Router, private toastr: ToastrService) {
    translate.setDefaultLang('fr');
    translate.use('fr');
    this.user = new FormGroup({
      phone: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8), Validators.maxLength(30)]),
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe((event: LangChangeEvent) => {
      if (this.translate.currentLang === 'ar') {
        $('#loginarea').css("text-align", "right")
        $('#logo_auth').css("text-align", "right")
        $('#slogan_container').removeClass("order-first").addClass("order-last")
        $('logo_container').removeClass("order-last").addClass("order-first")

      } if (this.translate.currentLang === 'fr') {
        $('#slogan_container').removeClass("order-last").addClass("order-first")
        $('logo_container').removeClass("order-first").addClass("order-last")
      }
    })
  }

  changeLang(val) {
    this.translate.use(val)
    this.currentLanguage = val
  }

  loginApi() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.authservice.loginApi(this.user.value).subscribe(res => {
      if (res) {
        localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(res));
        this.router.navigate(['/plaintes/new']);
        this.loading = false;
      }
    }, error => {
      this.loading = false;
      if (error.status === 400) {
        if (error.error.error === "Votre commune n\'est pas encore inscrit à Baladiaty encore!") {
          $('#not-found').click();
        } else {
          this.showError(error.error.error, 'Erreur!')
        }
      } else if (error.status === 403) {
        this.showError('Veuillez activer votre compte avant de connecter à baladiaty.tn', 'Compte non activé!');
        setTimeout(() => {
          localStorage.setItem('phone', this.user.value.phone);
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/sms');
        }, 2000);
      } else if (error.status === 402) {
        this.showError(error.error.error, 'Erreur!')
      }
    });
  }


  showError(txt, title) {
    this.toastr.error(txt, title);
  }

  public getCurrentlanguage(){
    this.currentLanguage = this.translate.currentLang
  }

}
```

I tried to get the current language by the service of ngx translate in the navbar.ts and set it as default language but thats not working ! I'm thinking to try use an event emitter and output decorator of angular but I don't know how to write that as the two components do not have a parent-child relationship